# Is there a compact Perl operation to slice alternate elements from an array?

Tags: perl, syntax

If I have an array `myarray` in Python, I can use the slice notation

```
myarray[0::2]
```

to select only the even-indexed elements. For example:

```
>>> ar = [ "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" ]
>>> ar [ 0 : : 2 ]
['zero', 'two', 'four', 'six']
```

Is there a similar facility in Perl?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's array slices:

```
my @slice = @array[1,42,23,0];
```

There's a way to to generate lists between $x and $y:

```
my @list = $x .. $y
```

There's a way to build new lists from lists:

```
my @new = map { $_ * 2 } @list;
```

And there's a way to get the length of an array:

```
my $len = $#array;
```

Put together:

```
my @even_indexed_elements = @array[map { $_ * 2 } 0 .. int($#array / 2)];
```

Granted, not quite as nice as the python equivalent, but it does the same job, and you can of course put that in a subroutine if you're using it a lot and want to save yourself from some writing.

Also there's quite possibly something that'd allow writing this in a more natural way in `List::AllUtils`.

Comment: Just be aware that if you have an empty array, this method will add an (empty) item to it (such that the new array is no longer of size 0).

Answer (score 24):

A Perl array slice is the `@` in front of the array name, then the list of indices you want:

```
 @array[@indices];
```

There's not a built-in syntax to select multiples, but it's not so hard. Use `grep` to produce a list of indices that you want:

```
 my @array = qw( zero one two three four five six );
 my @evens = @array[ grep { ! ($_ % 2) } 0 .. $#array ];
```

If you are using [PDL](http://pdl.perl.org), there are lots of nice slicing options.

Comment: I'd rather let you choose whether to use () or ==0.

Comment: Well, I can always edit later if I don't like the change. I try to fix those sorts of thinkos for other people. I'm not terribly picky about the code when it's the difference between right and wrong.

Answer (score 12):

I've written the module [List::Gen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Gen) on CPAN that provides an alternative way to do this:

```
use List::Gen qw/by/;

my @array = qw/zero one two three four five six/;

my @slice = map {$$_[0]} by 2 => @array;
```

`by` partitions `@array` into groups of two elements and returns an array of array references.  `map` then gets this list, so each `$_` in the map will be an array reference.  `$$_[0]` (which could also be written `$_->[0]`) then grabs the first element of each group that `by` created.

Or, using the `mapn` function which `by` uses internally:

```
use List::Gen qw/mapn/;

my @slice = mapn {$_[0]} 2 => @array;
```

Or, if your source list is huge and you may only need certain elements, you can use `List::Gen`'s lazy lists:

```
use List::Gen qw/by gen/;

my $slicer = gen {$$_[0]} by 2 => @array;
```

`$slicer` is now a lazy list (an array ref) that will generate it's slices on demand without processing anything that you didn't ask for.  `$slicer` also has a bunch of accessor methods if you don't want to use it as an array ref.

Answer (score 10):

I'll do this in a two-step process: first generate the desired indices, and then use a slice operation to extract them:

```
@indices = map { $_ * 2 } (0 .. int($#array / 2));
my @extracted = @array[@indices];
```

Step-by-step, thats:

- generate a list of integers from 0 to the last element of the array divided by two
- multiply each integer by two: now we have even numbers from zero to the index of the last element
- extract those elements from the original array

Answer (score 8):

Perl 6 will improve things dramatically, but (so far?) Perl 5 has pretty limited slicing capability: you have to explicitly specify the indexes you want, and it can't be open-ended.

So you'd have to do:

```
@ar = ( "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" );
print @ar[ grep $_ % 2 == 0, 0..$#ar ]
```

Answer (score 5):

One way to make this *prettier* is to wrap it in something like [`autobox`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/autobox/).

For example using [`autobox::Core`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/autobox-Core/):

```
use autobox::Core;
my @ar = qw/zero one two three four five six/;

# you could do this
@ar->slice_while( sub{ not $_ % 2 } );

# and this
@ar->slice_by(2);

# or even this
@ar->evens;
```

This is how you can define these autobox methods:

```
sub autobox::Core::ARRAY::slice_while {
    my ($self, $code) = @_;
    my @array;

    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#{ $self }; $i++) {
        local $_ = $i;
        push @array, $self->[ $i ] if $code->();
    }

    return wantarray ? @array : \@array;
}

sub autobox::Core::ARRAY::slice_by {
    my ($self, $by) = @_;
    my @array = @$self[ map { $_ * $by } 0 .. int( $#{$self} / $by )];
    return wantarray ? @array : \@array;
}

sub autobox::Core::ARRAY::evens {
    my $self  = shift;
    my @array = $self->slice_by(2);
    return wantarray ? @array : \@array;
}
```

/I3az/

Comment: I started working on an unmesh that did something similar, but then I went off to do something else. :)

Comment: I *oohed and aahed* for a couple of hours before I said *sod it* and decided that an `autobox` solution would be nice to see :)

Comment: ++ for all things [`autobox`](http://metacpan.org/pod/autobox::Core) .. especially `autobox::Core`.

Comment: @G.Cito - I agree.  In case you haven't seen it have a look at perl5i - https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5i

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about the order, and if the odd-numbered elements of the list are unique, you can concisely convert the array to a hash and take the `values`:

```
@even_elements = values %{{@array}};
@odd_elements = keys %{{@array}};
```

(No, this is not a serious answer)

Answer (score 2):

Another **way** would be by using `grep`:

```
my @array = qw( zero one two three four five six );

print map { "$_ " } @array[grep { !($_ & 1) } 0 .. $#array];  #even
Output:zero two four six

print map { "$_ " } @array[grep { ($_ & 1) } 0 .. $#array];  #odd
Output:one three five
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using an obscure feature of $| you can do this:

```
{
    local $|; # don't mess with global $|
    @ar = ( "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" );
    $| = 0;
    @even = grep --$|, @ar;
    $| = 1;
    @odd = grep --$|, @ar;
    print "even: @even\\n";
    # even: zero two four six
    print "odd: @odd\\n";
    # odd: one three five
}
```

or, as a 1 liner:

```
 { local $|=0; @even = grep --$|, @ar; }
```

Basically, --$| flip flops between a 0 and 1 value (despite the -- which normally decrements a numeric value), so grep sees a "true" value every other time, thus causing it to return every other item starting with the initial value of $|.  Note that you must start with 0 or 1, not some arbitrary index.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do {my $f =0; @even = grep {++$f%2} @ar; }

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest code without creating any index arrays:

```
sub even { my $f=0; return grep {++$f%2} @_; }
sub odd { my $f=1; return grep {++$f%2} @_; }
```