# Perl Command to join alternate array elements

Tags: perl

I am looking for a way to join alternate array elements in my Perl script. For instance, if I have the array:

```
[max, 123, min, 111, avg, 116]
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
Output: 123|111|116
```

Since I am new to perl, I was looking for a way to format it as shown in the output in the same command

Comment: Related: [Is there a compact Perl operation to slice alternate elements from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3925584/176646)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I was also looking for output in a particular format. I am new to perl and kind of struggling.

Comment: @swatcat If you're struggling, it helps to show exactly what code you're using and to explain why it's not doing what you want, so we can give you better guidance. Are you having trouble with one of the three answers below?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pairvalues` from [`List::Util`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#pairvalues):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use List::Util qw(pairvalues);

my @stats = qw(max 123 min 111 avg 116);
say join '|', pairvalues @stats;
```

#### Output:

```
123|111|116
```

Note that `pairvalues` was added to `List::Util` in version 1.29 (released in August, 2013), so you may need to upgrade the module if you're using an older Perl.

Also note that this will generate a warning and return an undefined element if your array contains an odd number of elements. A less-readable alternative that works for any size array is:

```
say join '|', @stats[ grep $_ % 2, 1..$#stats ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have access to an older version of List::Util, you can do it like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                     
use strict;
use warnings;

my @stats = qw(max 123 min 111 avg 116);
my $i;

print join '|',
    map  { $_->[1]     }   # value
    grep { $_->[0] % 2 }   # keep if index is odd
    map  { [$i++, $_]  }   # [ index, value ]
    @stats;
print "\n";
```

Output:

```
123|111|116
```

Answer (score -1):

Or `use List::Gen;` to obtain a range for slicing:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use List::Gen;

print 'Perl: ', $^V, '  List::Gen: ', $List::Gen::VERSION, "\n";

my $ar = ['max', 123, 'min', 111, 'avg', 116];
print 1, ' [', join('|', @$ar), "]\n";
print 2, ' [', join('|', @$ar[1, 3, 5]), "]\n";
my $r = range 1, scalar @$ar, 2;
print 3, ' [', join('|', @$ar[@$r]), "]\n";
print 4, ' [', join('|', @$ar[@{range 1, scalar @$ar, 2}]), "]\n";
```

output:

```
perl 31328310.pl
Perl: v5.10.0  List::Gen: 0.80
1 [max|123|min|111|avg|116]
2 [123|111|116]
3 [123|111|116]
4 [123|111|116]
```